# Opening new Scene from Controller JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am designing a Checkers Game and once the game is finished, a new window opens where you have the possibility to either start a new game or quit. I don't know much about JavaFX and I have been trying for a while now to get my code to work, but I stand without success...

I have the difficulty, that my board is not displayed as a fxml file, but it is being created with javacode and put in the center of my borderPane. The top of the borderPane is fxml-file. Then, the other window, once the game is over, is also another fxml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

 <Pane fx:id="paneMenu" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="240.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.GameMenuController">

<children>
 <Button fx:id="buttonRestart" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#restart" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="New Game" />
  <Button fx:id="buttonQuit" layoutX="139.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quit" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="Quit" />
  <Label fx:id="labelWinner" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="190.0" text="Label" textAlignment="CENTER" />
  <Text layoutX="50.0" layoutY="47.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Game over!" textAlignment="CENTER">
     <font>
        <Font size="26.0" />
     </font>
  </Text>
    </children>
   <padding>
  <Insets bottom="10.0" right="10.0" />
 </padding>
</Pane>
```

My Controller class for this fxml-file looks as follows:

```
public class GameMenuController implements Initializable {

public GameMenuController(Checkers model) {
    this.content = model;
}

Checkers content;

@FXML
private Label labelWinner;

@FXML
private Button buttonRestart;

@FXML
private Button buttonQuit;

@FXML
private Pane paneMenu;

BooleanProperty doRestart = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

@FXML
void restart(ActionEvent event) {
    content.cleanup();
    doRestart.set(true);
}

@FXML
void quit(ActionEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    labelWinner.setText("Winner here.");
    labelWinner.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        String s = " ";
        if (...);
        return s;
    }, content.whiteTurnProp));
}

}
```

And finally, in my main class I wanted to add a ChangeListener to the value doRestart in order to then recreate a new Scene.

My main class looks something like this:

```
public class Main extends Application{

Checkers content = new Checkers();
BorderPane border = new BorderPane(); 
Pane paneBoard = new Pane();
FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader();
FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    loader1.setLocation(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    loader1.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Class<?> aClass) {
            return new SampleController(content);
        }
    });

    loader2.setLocation(getClass().getResource("GameMenu.fxml"));
    loader2.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Class<?> aClass) {
            return new GameMenuController(content);
        }
    });   
    GameMenuController gameMenuControl = loader2.getController(); 

    Scene scene = new Scene(startGame());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Checkers");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    content.gameOver.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                try {
                    scene.setRoot(loader2.load());
                    primaryStage.setHeight(180);
                    primaryStage.setWidth(240);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

    gameMenuControl.doRestart.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue) {
            scene.setRoot(startGame());
            primaryStage.setHeight(scene.getHeight());
            primaryStage.setWidth(scene.getWidth());
            gameMenuControl.doRestart.set(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
protected Pane createContent() {

    paneBoard.setPrefSize(Checkers.WIDTH * Checkers.TILE_SIZE, Checkers.HEIGHT * Checkers.TILE_SIZE);
    paneBoard.getChildren().addAll(content.tileGroup, content.pieceGroup);

    for (int y = 0; y < Checkers.HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < Checkers.WIDTH; x++) {
            Tile tile = new Tile((x + y) % 2 == 0, x, y);
            Checkers.board[y][x] = tile;

            content.tileGroup.getChildren().add(tile);

            Piece piece = null;

            if (y <= 3 && (x + y) % 2 != 0) {
                piece = content.makePiece(PieceType.BLACK, x, y);
            }

            if (y >= 6 && (x + y) % 2 != 0) {
                piece = content.makePiece(PieceType.WHITE, x, y);
            }

            if (piece != null) {
                tile.setPiece(piece);
                content.pieceGroup.getChildren().add(piece);
            }
        }
    }

    return paneBoard;
}

protected BorderPane startGame() {
    try {
        border.setTop(loader1.load());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    border.setCenter(createContent());

    return border;
}

}
```

I am pretty sure that my code is a mess, I have been trying to work in as much of the tips given on here as possible, but since I am still super new to this, I don't really know how to go about it all.

What I would like to do, instead of using this change listener (which also doesn't work yet, Iam getting a NullPointerException), I'd like to change the view directly from my controller. How would I go about this?

1) Instead of creating the Controllers via Factory, can I give them somehow else access to my model Checkers? (all the game logic is stored there etc.)

2) How do I basically then recreate my first window? (created by `startGame()`)

Thank you very much!!
Best,
Lisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `GameMenuController gameMenuControl = loader2.getController()` *before* you call `loader2.load()`. The controller is created as part of the load process, so `gameMenuControl` is going to be null.

You could simply move the calls to `loader2.getController()` and `gameMenuControl.doRestart.addListener(...)` to immediately after calling `loader2.load()`.

Alternatively, just create the controller yourself, instead of delegating to the controller factory. **Remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the FXML file**, and then do:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    // You can make similar changes to loader1 if you want...

    loader2.setLocation(getClass().getResource("GameMenu.fxml"));

    GameMenuController gameMenuControl = new GameMenuController(content) ;

    gameMenuControl.doRestart.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue) {
            scene.setRoot(startGame());
            primaryStage.setHeight(scene.getHeight());
            primaryStage.setWidth(scene.getWidth());
            gameMenuControl.doRestart.set(false);
            }
        }
    });

    loader2.setController(gameMenuControl);

    content.gameOver.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                try {
                    scene.setRoot(loader2.load());
                    primaryStage.setHeight(180);
                    primaryStage.setWidth(240);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

    Scene scene = new Scene(startGame());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Checkers");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}
```